# Cannot center section within the image in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm new to Next.js. I have the HomePage within the pages folder, and I'm trying to center the `<h1></h1>` in the middle of the picture but instead, it pushes it down. Here is my code...

```
import image from '../public/images/background.jpg'
import Image from "next/image";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

export default function HomePage() {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <main>
                <Image
                    src={image}
                    alt="Programming"
                    className="absolute object-cover w-full h-full"
                />
                <section className="relative flex justify-center min-h-screen pt-12 lg:pt-64 px-8">
                    <h1 className="text-6xl text-green-100 font-bold cursive leading-none lg:leading-snug home-name">Hi. I'm
                        Shloimi</h1>
                </section>
            </main>
        </Layout>

    )
}
```

Can someone help me, please. And I'm using Tailwind.css

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  <main className="relative">
    <Image
      src={image}
      alt="Programming"
      className="w-full h-full bg-cover"
    />
    <h1 className="absolute w-full text-6xl font-bold leading-none text-center text-green-100 top-1/2 transform translate-y-1/2 cursive lg:leading-snug home-name ">
      asdf
    </h1>
  </main>
```

I deleted `pt-12 lg:pt-64` to make your goal and inserted `items-center`, but if you want to use `pt`, then you can customise with that values.

Happy coding :)

Comment: nope, still pushes it down. It does not help

Comment: because your `Image/next` getting their area. so your `section` tag would be posited below.

Comment: So how could I fix it, that it should be nicely in the middle of the image

Comment: check `HTML` and `CSS` in this https://play.tailwindcss.com/KMIAJVxPN3 . I just replace you Image component to `div`

Comment: ok,  but that still does not help me, since the `<Image />` component takes up the screen and section pushes it down. in your example, you're just adding an image url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234425/discussion-between-shlomo-minkowicz-and-jswizard).